# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in MVC Layout = null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting a strange error located in

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

This is the error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

And the stack trace :

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]      
ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in f:\Web Prog\my work\mcpd\mvc\FilippoPhotography\FP.WebUI\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:4    
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197    
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97     
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17    
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62    
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76    
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260    
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115    
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13    
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242   
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177       
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43    
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47    
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9    
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Here's my controller of this view :

```
namespace FP.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IInfoRepo repo;
        public HomeController(IInfoRepo repoParam)
        {
            repo = repoParam;
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            Info model = repo.Info.FirstOrDefault();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the view itself :

```
@model FP.Domain.Entities.Info

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>A.Filippo Photography</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/whole.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Homepage.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="whole_wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="follow">
                <a href="http://@Model.Facebook.Substring(Model.Facebook.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Facebook.Length)"><img src="~/Content/img/temp.png" alt="facebook"/></a>
                <a href="http://@Model.Twitter.Substring(Model.Twitter.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Twitter.Length)"><img src="~/Content/img/temp.png" alt="twitter"/></a>
                <a href="mailto://@Model.Email"><img src="~/Content/img/temp.png" alt="email"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="iconlabel">
                <a href="~/Views/Home/Index"><img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="main_content">
                <div id="slides_wrapper">
                    <a href="gallery.aspx">
                        <div id="gallery_slide">                        
                            <p>Gallery</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="sessions.aspx">
                        <div id="session_slide">
                            <p>Sessions</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="offers.aspx">
                        <div id="offers_slide">
                            <p>Offers</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="about.aspx">
                        <div id="about_slide">
                            <p>About Us</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="contact.aspx">
                        <div id="contact_slide">
                            <p>Contact Us</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>                
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <div id="copyright">
                    <div id="rights">
                        <p>All rights reserved.© - Best viewed using the latest version of <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a> or <a href="www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">Mozilla Firefox</a>.</p>                    
                    </div>
                    <div id="stamp">                    
                        <p>Crafted by</p>
                        <a href="http://about.me/rafael.adel">Rafael Adel</a>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm getting frustrated here. Thanks.

Comment: Put your full code here.. I'm sure you are using your `Layout` anywhere else..

Comment: What is your `Index.cshtml`, line 4 looks like?

Comment: if you set a break point, are you certain the model is populated?

Comment: Are you sure that properties in your model like @Model.Facebook are not returning null? have you tried rendering an empty view? or perhaps putting breakpoints on these calls to see if they come up null?

Comment: Your `model.Facebook` or your `model.Twitter` property is `null`. This is causing the exception. Visual Studio just displays it wrongly on the `Layout = null;`

Comment: Hmm, you guys are right. `model` is null. What really caused me confusion is the location VS showed the error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nemesv you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possible exception lines:

```
<a href="http://@Model.Facebook.Substring(Model.Facebook.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Facebook.Length)"><img src="~/Content/img/temp.png" alt="facebook"/></a>
<a href="http://@Model.Twitter.Substring(Model.Twitter.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Twitter.Length)"><img src="~/Content/img/temp.png" alt="twitter"/></a>
```

Possibly the code `Info model = repo.Info.FirstOrDefault();` returns a default which means null and calling any method like `Substring()` with null causes an exception.